# Regex to extract all matches of several patterns from a single string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

After three hours I'm going to stop banging my head on the wall and ask for help. This ought to be an easy regex, but I just can't quite get my mind around it today.

Given a short string and a few different patterns, I need to extract all the matching patterns from the string, where each pattern is a "whole word".

The patterns are: `"YES", "NO", "MAYBE"`, any sequence of asterisks `['*', '**', '***', '...']`, any number from 0 to 999, with the case of the text being case-insensitive.

So if `s = 'foo yes and no doo 5 boo **** bar far 13 not but no'` the result would be `["yes", "no", "5", "****", "13", "no"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = 'foo yes and no doo 5 boo * *** bar far 13 not but no YESTERDAY'
ms = s.scan(/(?:\b(?:yes|no|\d{1,3})\b|\*+)/i)
ms # => ["yes", "no", "5", "*", "***", "13", "no"]
```

Comment: This would hit on the `not` too.

Comment: yes, it produces that extra "no" from 'not'...  ["yes", "no", "5", "*", "***", "13", "no", "no", "YES"].I wasnt sure how to tell it to hit only whole words?

Comment: @jpwynn: I overlooked that point in your question, the update should fix it.

Comment: it misses the last 'yes' if it's the end of the string... produces ["yes", "no", "5", "*", "***", "13", "no"] from  s = 'foo yes and no doo 5 boo * *** bar far 13 not but no YES'

Comment: it's so close... do you do this all day? cuz i find geenrating a regex makes my head hurt!